# In proj4string(shp) : CRS object has comment, which is lost in output

Tags: r, tmap

Using the code below, I am trying to read a shapefile. This used to work properly but not with my recently upgraded R/Rstudio. I got this error:

> In proj4string(shp) : CRS object has comment, which is lost in output

I used devtools to install oldtmaptools that hosts the read_shape function. Is there any way to fix this?

P.S: I know readOGR might be an alternative but for some reason, I prefer to use the read_shape function.

```
# the shape file is downloadable from: https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2017/shp/
usshapefile <- "cb_2017_us_state_500k.shp"
nhgeo <- read_shape(file=usshapefile, as.sf = TRUE)
```

Comment: [This appears to be a warning message](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364667/r-4-0-1-not-sure-i-understand-this-message-warning-message-in-proj4stringx) rather than an error and is related to changes in recent changes in `rgdal` concerning PROJ6.